# Using AWS SDK to help call and allow a user create a tracker API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-location-service

Ive been trying to create a form where users can provide a name and location then create a tracker, to be used alongside Location Services Maps. I fee like i am close but am not sure why its not working nor rendering.

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344)

Answer (score 0):

A few initial thoughts based on the code snippet you shared:

- I don't know enough about your use case, you wouldn't need to have more than one tracker per asset type when tracking moving objects. If that's the case for you, create trackers using AWS CLI or AWS Console.
- If you'd like to create trackers using the JavaScript SDK, first, you need to authenticate your request. See [Prerequisites for using Amazon Location Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/gs-prereqs.html) and [Geofencing and Tracking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/start-tracking.html) to get more information.
- Check your input parameters (`params`) against the [CreateTracker API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location-trackers/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTracker.html) requirements and make sure you're using the right parameters and passing the right values.
- Check your browser's console and post the errors you're getting here to help me better understand the issue.
- Note that `createTracker` creates a new tracker that does not have any data - this means that there is nothing to render yet. To track your assets, you'll need to send position updates to the tracker. See [Start Tracking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/start-tracking.html) for an example.

Share a bit more about your use case, i.e., what is it you're trying to do. That'll help me better understand the problem.

UPDATE: here is what I'd do for your use case:

- Create a tracker using [AWS Console or AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/start-tracking.html).
- Use [AWS Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/) to push position updates to the tracker when building iOS or Android apps.
- Use AWS IoT Core to send position updates to the tracker when building something else like a web app. See [Tracking using MQTT with Amazon Location Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/tracking-using-mqtt.html) for an example. I'd consider [AWS Amplify PubSub](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/pubsub/getting-started/q/platform/js/) to send/receive messages to AWS IoT Core when building on the web.
- Send metadata like the name of the food truck, food type, etc. along with position updates using `PositionProperties` - see [Update your tracker with a device position](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/start-tracking.html). This would help me attach more information for data visualization or analysis purposes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info. I am trying to create a real time taco truck finder. I want a user (Truck owner) to be able to post their truck via tracker for other to be able to search and find. I have maps up with unauthenticated access already but am having trouble making a way for a user to create the tracker.

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing. I updated my answer to cover your use case.